# Reduce the image to the text contents using scikit image

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image

Here is the image from which I want to take the text out.

[image]

How to remove the black border and reduce the image to only 50?

Approach I took:

1. I tried to use corner detectors (corner peak and corner harris) and pick the first 2 coordinates from the left and last 2 coordinates from the right.
2. With those 4 coordinates I cropped the image and I further reduced by 5 on all sides.

Certainly not efficient way of doing it. I also looked at few segmentation also. Not able to get it right. I am using scikit image for solving this.

Answer (score 2):

Using corners might not work since corner points can also be present in characters.

Here is what i tried with hough lines as described below:

1) First erode the image to minimize the gap between lines and characters

2) Use Hough line detection algorithm to detect and delete the lines

3) Dilate the image to get clear characters

4) Now we have characters and lines separated, so we can delete the lines by finding the connected components.

Here is the code implementation of the same in Python:

```
img = cv2.imread('D:\Image\st1.png',0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

#dilate the image to reduce gap between characters and lines and get hough lines correctly
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)

#find canny edge image
canny = cv2.Canny(erosion,100,200)

minLineLength=img.shape[1]/4
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=canny,rho=0.02,theta=np.pi/500, threshold=10,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=10)

a,b,c = lines.shape
# delete the lines
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(erosion, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), 0, 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

#erode the image 
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations=1)

# find connected components
connectivity = 4
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(erosion, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1]; nb_components = nb_components - 1
min_size = 250 #threshhold value for lines length 
img2 = np.zeros((output.shape), np.uint8)
for i in range(0, nb_components):
    if sizes[i] >= min_size:
        img2[output == i + 1] = 255 #delete the line components

img = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)
```

Output image:

[image: Output image]